# How to exit webpack cli after successfull compilation of react app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have been using webpack with Django recently. I want to know how to exit the webpack-CLI after successful compilation of the App.js and not hang in there and watch the files for updates. Any idea what command I should run after npm run webpack... or should I run something else?

Comment: *edit its compilation .... sorry for the spelling mistake.

Comment: It's a bit unclear from your post what your problem is. Could you be a bit more clear on what issue you are facing?

Comment: Well, I actually solved it... I made a simple CLI package to integrate django with react.. you can check it out . It's called dact. just do pip install dact and it will be installed.

Comment: thanks for asking though @sunero4 !!